# Which physical core does the operating system use?

Tags: cpu, operating-systems, multi-core

The operating system needs to be running on one or more physical cores of a multi-core processor, right? Is it possible to identify which those physical cores are using a piece of code?

Comment: Not precisely. But if you got a program with high CPU usage, you can look at individual core usage in Task Manager to know it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the operating system (kernel) is a part of every single process that runs on the machine. So in actuality, it's not like the operating system is running on one core while user programs are running on the other cores, but rather user processes are running on every core and every single time they need to interact with the operating system, they issue a system call which transfers control to the operating system *on that same core*.

So, the kernel is running on all cores and most operating systems will tell you what percentage the kernel is using of each core, which is actually a measure of both how often the userspace programs interact with the kernel and how often the kernel interrupts the userspace processes for scheduling, hardware management, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what OS you use. At least with the ones supporting `dtrace`, you certainly can measure the kernel CPU load per core.

`mpstat` which is based on sampling can also report detailed per core CPU load statistics.

Unless dedicated sets/cpu binding/affinity or similar techniques are used, the kernel part of the CPU load should be balanced between all cores.